# why unit test mocks always null with controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking

Want to unit test uses mocks my data is actually stored in memory,Why always get **null** from controller response result.

Here is my controller

```
private readonly IUnitOfWorkAsync _unitOfWorkAsync;
        private readonly IVersionService _versionService;
        public VersionController(IUnitOfWorkAsync unitOfWorkAsync, IVersionService versionService)
        {
            this._unitOfWorkAsync = unitOfWorkAsync;
            this._versionService = versionService;
        }


        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var versions =  _versionService.Queryable();
            return View(versions);
        }
```

Here is my unit test code:

```
private Mock<IVersionService> _versionServiceMock;
        private Mock<IUnitOfWorkAsync> _unitOfWorkAsync;

        VersionController objController;
        List<Model.Models.Version> listVersion;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Initialize()
        {

            _versionServiceMock = new Mock<IVersionService>();
            _unitOfWorkAsync = new Mock<IUnitOfWorkAsync>();
            objController = new VersionController(_unitOfWorkAsync.Object, _versionServiceMock.Object);

            listVersion = new List<Model.Models.Version>() {
             new Model.Models.Version() { AppName="App 1",ObjectState=ObjectState.Added,AuditField=new AuditFields()},
             new Model.Models.Version() { AppName="App 2",AppVersion="1.0",ObjectState=ObjectState.Added,AuditField=new AuditFields()},
             new Model.Models.Version() { AppName="App 3",ObjectState=ObjectState.Added,AuditField=new AuditFields()}
            };
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Version_Get_All()
        {
            //Arrange
            _versionServiceMock.Setup(x => x.Query().Select()).Returns(listVersion);

            //Act
            var result = (( objController.Index() as ViewResult).Model) as List<Model.Models.Version>;


        }
```

Why in result always get null,How to check why null is getting.

Note: i use [this](https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/) pattern in my project controller.

Comment: Most likely you setup one method but controller calls another... [MCVE] could help to verify that, but probably would be too long - consider to debug your code yourself instead.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov Thanks for your reply,after debug i confirm 100 percent controller call methods are not wrong.Please show me some guideline how to find what's actually going on.As i say i used URF framework they used hibernate,is it the root of the problem.Thank you

Comment: shamim, note that you've accepted post that demonstrates my comment - you setup `Query`, but controller calls `Queryable`. Please make sure that answer actually answer your question (rather than just thank you for discussion in the comments of answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moq creates it's own implementation of interface when mocking. By default all methods on mocked interface will return null.

Try to mock `_versionService.Queryable()` instead. Like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Version_Get_All()
{
     //Arrange
    _versionServiceMock.Setup(x => x.Queryable()).Returns(listVersion);

     //Act
    var result = (( objController.Index() as ViewResult).Model) as List<Model.Models.Version>;


}
```

Comment: As per listVersion is list so i need to replace this with listVersion.AsQueryable() , Still i get result=null

Comment: try `return View(versions.ToList());` in controller

Comment: @ Kovalenko Ivan,Thanks for your reply it's now working ,will you please tell me why i need to add to list in my controller.

Comment: @shamim because you are casting your model to `List<Model.Models.Version>` in test, but your method `x.Queryable()` returns `IQueryable<Model.Models.Version>`.

Comment: I try your approach on my another method async type, there it's not work,suppose my controller event look like :public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            var versions = await _versionService.GetsAsync();
            return View(versions.ToList());
        }

Comment: Here's a good [article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-unit-tests-part-2-right-way.html) about testing async methods.

Comment: @ Kovalenko Ivan,after follow your article i failed to understand how to use it with my controller,Sorry for lack of my knowledge.will you please show me some syntax

Comment: thanks for your valuable effort,it's really helpful for me.thank you.One thing i can not debug on following code block             Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var executionResult = await _service.GetsAsync();                
                //Assert
                Assert.AreEqual(executionResult.Count(), 3);
            }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

Comment: want to see executionResult

Comment: put a breakpoint inside `{ var executionResult = await _service.GetsAsync(); Assert.AreEqual(executionResult.Count(), 3); }` not on task.

Comment: great man thank you,hope you understand i am new in unit testing.Will you suggest me how do i increase knowledge in unit test field.